why doesnt groups goes to main query when grouped by in subquery
select sum(age),customer_id 
from (select * from customers group by first_name)

why does these 2 codes are not equivalent?
select sum(age),customer_id 
from customers 
group by first_name


'If you use an aggregate function in a statement containing no GROUP BY clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html

@KIKOSoftware can you answer now?\

@P.Salmon but the groups have been made in the subquery, so why theres need of group by?

'a subquery in a SELECT statement FROM clause is a derived table:' - hence a group by may be required for your query but put it another way if you did want to collapse the result to one row would you have to invent an ungroup_by

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html

The subquery is executed before the remaining part of the main query.
SELECT age, customer_id
FROM customers
GROUP BY first_name

This subquery takes all customers and groups them by their first name. Weirdly enough, MySQL allows you to select age and customer_id, eventhough they are not necessarily unique per group. It might pick any values here, possibly even the age of one customer in the group and the id of another one.
Then, the result of this subquery (it is a table with columns age and customer_id, let's call this table t) is used as a table in the "outer" query like this:
SELECT SUM(age), customer_id
FROM t

As SUM(age) is an aggregate, all rows of t are aggregated into one row for the final output. Again quite weird behavior of MySQL is happening for the customer_id: any value might be chosen.
What you might want to do instead:
SELECT first_name, SUM(age)
FROM customers
GROUP BY first_name

This seems to be the only meaningful query you might want to try... it puts all customers with the same first name into a group and sums up their ages, returning the common first name alongside the sum.

Why my code isnt showing the same output that yours code do(group by and sum(age) in main query)? My code should pass groups from subquery and then use aggregate function sum(age) for each group. Please explain this.
